how to install the 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' on a Databricks cluster?
I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server from an Azure Databricks notebook using the pyodbc Python library. When I run the query, I encounter the following error:
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Before executing the query, I tried to install the ODBC driver using the following commands:
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

However, I received these warning messages:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0  10611      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10684
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
E: This command can only be used by root.
bash: line 2: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

This is the cluster configuration I am currently using.
Summary
1-2 Workers 14-28 GB Memory  
4-8 Cores 1
Driver 14 GB Memory, 4 Cores
Runtime 14.3.x-scala2.12
Unity Catalog, Standard_DS3_v2, 1–3 DBU/h

Could you assist me in installing the ODBC driver on the Databricks cluster mentioned above?

From the Microsoft documentation:
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

Output:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0   9140      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9186
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)
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=J6gs
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    88  100    88    0     0    975      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   977
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy mainGet:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease [3,632 B]
Hit:2 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages [150 kB]
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main armhf Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main arm64 Packages [37.7 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main all Packages [1,035 B]
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 205 kB in 2s (126 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  odbcinst
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  msodbcsql17 odbcinst
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 756 kB of archives.
After this operation, 53.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 msodbcsql17 amd64 17.10.6.1-1 [746 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 odbcinst amd64 2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1 [9,930 B]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 756 kB in 1s (925 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst.
(Reading database ... 91317 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../odbcinst_2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking odbcinst (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package msodbcsql17.
Preparing to unpack .../msodbcsql17_17.10.6.1-1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Unpacking msodbcsql17 (17.10.6.1-1) ...
Setting up odbcinst (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up msodbcsql17 (17.10.6.1-1) ...
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1. 
    Target directory is /etc
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)
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=J6gs
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    88  100    88    0     0    975      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   977
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy mainGet:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease [3,632 B]
Hit:2 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages [150 kB]
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main armhf Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main arm64 Packages [37.7 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main all Packages [1,035 B]
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 205 kB in 2s (126 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  odbcinst
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  msodbcsql17 odbcinst
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 756 kB of archives.
After this operation, 53.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 msodbcsql17 amd64 17.10.6.1-1 [746 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 odbcinst amd64 2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1 [9,930 B]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 756 kB in 1s (925 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst.
(Reading database ... 91317 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../odbcinst_2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking odbcinst (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package msodbcsql17.
Preparing to unpack .../msodbcsql17_17.10.6.1-1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Unpacking msodbcsql17 (17.10.6.1-1) ...
Setting up odbcinst (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up msodbcsql17 (17.10.6.1-1) ...
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1. 
    Target directory is /etc
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)
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=J6gs
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    88  100    88    0     0    975      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   977
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy mainGet:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease [3,632 B]
Hit:2 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages [150 kB]
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main armhf Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main arm64 Packages [37.7 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main all Packages [1,035 B]
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 205 kB in 2s (126 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  odbcinst
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  msodbcsql17 odbcinst
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 756 kB of archives.
After this operation, 53.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 msodbcsql17 amd64 17.10.6.1-1 [746 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 odbcinst amd64 2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1 [9,930 B]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 756 kB in 1s (925 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst.
(Reading database ... 91317 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../odbcinst_2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking odbcinst (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package msodbcsql17.
Preparing to unpack .../msodbcsql17_17.10.6.1-1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Unpacking msodbcsql17 (17.10.6.1-1) ...
Setting up odbcinst (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up msodbcsql17 (17.10.6.1-1) ...
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1. 
    Target directory is /etc
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...


Despite following your solution, I am still encountering the following error:
bash: line 2: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list: Permission denied
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

This issue arises because we require a multi-node cluster with shared access mode, which prevents me from installing the ODBC driver. Could you assist me with this?

This appears to be a permission issue with UC enabled workspace. ODBC driver not working - Azure databricks unity catalog enabled. The script worked just fine on a Standard Workspace.

Came back to add, I don't have a UC enabled workspace available to test, but comments in the above link suggest you'd have to use init scripts to install the driver. Hope that helps!

In order to install ODBC driver on Databricks you can follow below steps:
For All Purpose cluster:
You can run below script from your databricks notebook in the cell with the magic command of %sh
#!/bin/bash
# Download the Microsoft signing key
echo "Downloading Microsoft signing key..."
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
# Add the Microsoft repository for ODBC Driver 18
echo "Adding Microsoft repository..."
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
# Update the package index
echo "Updating package index again..."
sudo apt-get update
# Install the ODBC Driver 17
echo "Installing ODBC Driver 17..."
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# Install oDBC Driver Manager
# echo "Installing ODBC Driver manager ..."
sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
# Check if the driver is installed
echo "Checking installed driver..."
dpkg -L msodbcsql17
echo "ODBC Driver installation completed successfully."

After running this script, you can also verify whether the ODBC driver has been installed successfully or not by running below python code in notebook:
pip install pyodbc

import pyodbc

def check_unixodbc():
    try:
        # List available ODBC drivers
        drivers = [driver for driver in pyodbc.drivers()]
        print("Available ODBC Drivers:")
        for driver in drivers:
            print(driver)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')

check_unixodbc()

Running the above code would display all the ODBC drivers installed on the databricks clusters.
For Job Clusters:
There are two options:

Have the first task run the notebook with the above code on the cluster and use that same cluster in the second task where you are making use of the ODBC driver.
Use the above shell script and save it as an .sh file. If you are on windows and use notepad++ to save the file, make sure the EOL Conversion is Unix (LF) and not Windows (LF) otherwise the script might run successfully but the driver won't get installed on the cluster.
You need to run the above shell script using init scripts on the databricks job cluster.


there are the way thay I install ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, I sure it's the same, and pretty sure that you can work with 18 without changing your code.
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install unixodbc
sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get --assume-yes install msodbcsql18
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get --assume-yes install mssql-tools18
sudo apt-cache search msodbcsql
sudo apt-cache search mssql-tools
sudo echo 'export PATH=\"$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin\"' >> ~/.bashrc
sudo source ~/.bashrc


I tried installing ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server using the following commands:
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

However, I am still encountering the same error.

Did you add a location of a driver to $PATH variable as done here:
sudo echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
sudo source ~/.bashrc

I don't believe this will work with Unity Catalog due to isolation level.
